# How to launch a c program from another c program

Tags: c

I have a c program which I can launch at command prompt.
Is it possible for me the lunch this application in my another c program?
If yes, how? All the google result shows me how to do that using pthread? Will that work? 
I suspect that I need a new process for my c program.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to do this in Windows or linux?

Comment: I am trying this on Linux (Ubuntu 9.10). So it is more efficient to do fork() than system()? Since an user comments systems fork() twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is system specific, but there is commonly `execve` or something like that and there is always `system("/path/to/program");` that you can use that is also system specific

Comment: Keep in mind that `system()` forks *twice* – Its argument is passed to the shell/command interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into using `fork()` and `exec()`?
Fork will split a process, exec lets you start a new program from one of the instanaces that was `fork`'d.

First hit on google:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html

As others have mentioned, the details may vary depending on what OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to an explicit `fork`/`exec` and `system`, there is `popen`. (All in a unixish environment).

You'll get better help if you are more explicit about what your operating environment is and how you need to interact with the daughter process.

Answer (score 0):

The [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) function is the way to go in Windows.

You can use the [system()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/system.html) function to literally make commands against the console, but I don't remember if it blocks or not.

For linux look into [execv](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execl.htm). [This page](http://www.gidforums.com/t-3369.html) has a linux parent launching a child application example in linux include a communications pipe between the two..

Also, [execve](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/execve.2.html) will launch by executable filename.